# How do i download a CSV file via API using laravel, VUE, and NUXT.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, laravel-api

Basically, all the code on the API side exists and works.
We can assume that.

Also, I am pretty sure that the frontend Vue code works also.

The trouble I am running into is that when you press the export button,
We get a CORs error. We have no other CORs problems at all. Everything works as expected. EXCEPT for this file download. I did attach the exportPDF method.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at URL from origin https://localhost has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

COMPLETE RAW:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://example.com/api/v2/messages?Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*&Content-Disposition=form-data&csv_fields[]=id&csv_fields[]=item_id&csv_fields[]=promo_item_id&csv_fields[]=title&csv_fields[]=sent_at&csv_fields[]=sent_total&sort=sent_at%7Cdesc' 
from origin 'https://localhost:3030' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I made a couple poor attempts in the request to include `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` but this does nothing. As is expected. The last time i had to handle a file with API i made a web route to solve it, but that doesn't actually solve the problem. it just bypasses the API.
You can see the note from the previous developer "`// need to handle downloading the file.`"

Thoughts?

```
async exportCsv() {
  await this.$axios
    .$get(this.getRoute('index'), {
      params: {
        // My Poor attempt next two lines: 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Disposition': 'form-data',
        csv_fields: this.headerValues,
        sort: this.table.sort[0],
        ...this.filters
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // need to handle downloading the file.
      // currently CORS is not handling the request
      if (response.data.task) {
        this.$store.dispatch('snackbar/show', {
          message: `Export successfully requested. ID: ${response.data.task}`
        })
      }
    })
},
```

Here's my export code, this comes from a method called Tablify that we use to format code to return to Vue datatables.

There's a `if ($request->has('csv_fields'))` and it calls this method.

```
use MyCompany\Jobs\ExportCsvJob;

/**
 * Exports the request into a CSV file.
 */
protected function exportCsv(Request $request, Builder $builder)
{
    $fields = collect(Arr::wrap($request->input('csv_fields')));
    $fields = $fields->filter(function ($field) {
        return $this->getTableColumns()->contains($field);
    })->toArray();

    if ($builder->count() <= 1000) {
        return export_csv($fields, $builder->get()); // <-- See func below
    }

    $task = Task::make([
        'name' => 'Exporting CSV',
        'description' => 'Exporting CSV',
        'data' => [
            'download' => '',
        ],
    ]);
    auth()->user()->tasks()->save($task);

    ExportCsvJob::dispatch($fields, $task, $builder);

    return ['task' => $task->id];
}

function export_csv(array $fields, Collection $data, $filename = 'export.csv')
{
    CsvExport::output($fields, $data, $filename);

    if ('testing' !== App::environment()) {
        exit;
    }
}

public static function output(array $fields, Collection $data, $filename = 'export.csv')
{
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin *'); <-- just added that. 
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv($output, $fields);
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        fputcsv($output, self::createRowFromItem($fields, $item));
    }

    fclose($output);
}
```

After i added that header: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin *');
I now get a ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I have not seen any other questions directly related to getting a file through an API.

Thanks in advance stack fam!

Comment: Can I solve this? This working with laravel >7, please help me.

Comment: Please, can you help me !

Comment: Usually when you have your dev environment set up correctly and you run into a cors error, it's associated with a php error that laravel cannot manage to log. Since I made this question, I passed this off a frontend dev. So sorry, cannot answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in fact when using dd () in the controller it returns cors error, from what I read in the fuitcake documentation, so notice that in my controller I was using phpspreedsheet and doing $ writer-> save ('php: // output ')

Answer (score 0):

Laravel > 7.x can automatically respond to CORS OPTIONS requests with values that you configure. All CORS settings may be configured in your `cors` configuration file and OPTIONS requests will automatically be handled by the `HandleCors` middleware that is included by default in your global middleware stack.

For more information on CORS and CORS headers, please consult the [MDN web documentation on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers) and the [laravel-cors](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) package that its include in Laravel > 7.

If you have an older version of Laravel you can install this package in a compatible version.

Comment: Yes we run 7.x. and we have a cors config. 
I will check that out further. Thanks bud.

Comment: See. That's the thing. We have the cors installed and published, and it works. 
We can talk to the API, but i have no idea how to allow file downloads.

Comment: You have to give more information about what you are doing on the server side.

Comment: It doesn't seem that we have much configured besides the base set up of  fruitcake/laravel-cors. There's not much to tell. There's no custom code in here per se. 
If you follow this article, it basically explains what we have set up. 
And for some reason, it doesn't allow file downloads. 
https://www.positronx.io/how-to-enable-cors-in-laravel/

Comment: I mean the code to download the file you need. It is a CSV file generated so it should have some code to show.

Comment: Added more. See above.

Comment: As far as I can see you are not returning a file for download. Unless the export_csv method returns a csv file the rest doesn't make much sense to run a Job

Comment: I added the rest of the method stack. That should be everything.

Comment: The worst part is that our last version worked great, but this one does not work at all. Same stack. Vue API. This is really driving me up a tree. I am pretty sure this has to do with VUE and returning a file. Like I'm missing a config setting or something stupid

Comment: Have you tried insomnia or postman to verify that you are returning the correct content? From here I see everything well, however, if you have the configuration enabled with the cors package is not necessary to add the head again, can generate conflicts in my experience.